# images are not set on screen properly?

Tags: android, xml

I am making splash screen which background have images.I put 480x800 size image in drawable hdpi similarly rest of mdpi(320x480),lpdi(240x320).

Problem is that when i test hdpi emulator or other emulator image is not fit

code is as-

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/splash" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ImageView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

set into actvity simply..

Answer (score 1):

Screens resolution is one thing but screen dimensions is something else.
If you want to fill up full screen try using

```
android:scaleType = "fitXY"
```

in xml file. But this will stretch pic. If your pic is not scaling right
try using **draw9patch** in android sdk tools folder.

If not, try to play with others scaleType methods.

Answer (score 0):

did you check out the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) property? You can set it to center or something else and see if it scales now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`ImageView.ScaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android:scaleType` attribute inside ImageView.

To know more about this property, go here => [android:scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType)